# Carrying deadlines and cancelation signals across processes

Tags: go

The golang [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) documentation says :

> Package context defines the Context type, which carries deadlines, 
>     cancelation signals, and other request-scoped values across API boundaries 
>     and between processes.

I also read concrete [examples](https://blog.golang.org/context) of context, but I don't see any information on `carring deadlines and cancellation signals` across **processes**.

How does signals work across processes?

Are they reliable like, if service1 sends a cancel signal but it dies, and signal is lost, what happens now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to break your enthusiasm, but the [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package cannot be used as-is for inter-process communication and signaling.

The wording here may be a little imperfect, as in the "context" of the `context` package documentation most people would think of *"processes"* as an [OS process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) entity. But the word "process" has multiple meanings, and the more general *"a set of activities that interact to achieve a result"* meaning is used here (from [Wikipedia: Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process)). To avoid ambiguity, *"goroutines"* or *"a set of goroutines"* would be more appropriate here, but within the *same* Go application.

Note that when the `context` package was first published as a separate, experimental package (not as part of the standard library), this blog post explained its background and uses: [Go Concurrency Patterns: Context](https://blog.golang.org/context). The `context` haven't change since it was integrated into the standard library, and that blog post did not mention the word "process", not even once.

Comment: In [this video](https://youtu.be/LSzR0VEraWw?t=1100) (linked at relevant timestamp), he creates an http server which gets `r.Context()` from the request, and then `select`s on `ctx.Done()`.  He runs the server in one terminal, a client in another, and the `ctrl-C`'s the client before the request finishes.  The server detects this even in `ctx.Done()`.  How is this happening?

Comment: @Jonah When you press `ctrl+c` on the client, that terminates the connection to the server, and when the server detects the closed connection, cancels the request's context which means its `done` channel will be closed, and so any handler that "listens" on the context's `done` channel will also be notified and can return early from the handler function.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it was something like that but after exploring the source of the http package I was unable to find where the code was that implemented that feature